# MYSQL : Inner Join On Three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK6wX.png)

[needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZnYT.png)

Please Help Me .

Comment: did you even try solving it?

Comment: Please use text (not image) whenever possible.

Comment: Yes Bro I Tried hard But no success . Then I post this question.

Comment: 1. Show your attempts. That includes attempts at parts. 2. You have not explained what your example result is an example of. Explain what rows appear in the result in terms of what rows appear in the input.

Comment: @GurV Please do not blindly include links for OPs. Those should not be images, they should be text. And the OP should be told that. This question should not have made it out of the review queues. It should not have been answered either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Select a.roll_no, name, sport_name
from
student a
inner join
student_details b
on a.roll_no=b.roll_no
inner join
sports c
on b.sport_id=c.sport_id
where a.roll_no in (1,3);
```

'Where' condition here helps restrict out to just Sandeep and Ajay. If you want for all then remove 'Where' condition completely

Comment: Thank You Very Much For Your help!